# Foreign key in phpmyadmin giving error in newsfeed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on newsfeed and I hope I this right but I want that the image that is uploaded, is linked to the user who uploads it. I have 2 tables.

`users` in here the accounts are stored.

`picas` in here the uploaded images are stored.

I have in `users` a primary key called `user_id` and I have in the `picas` table a primary key called `id`.
I made in `picas` a new colomn called `user_id` and when an image is uploaded I tell PHP to get the id from the user who is logged in and then insert that within the `user_id` colomn from the table `picas` so I can see which user uploaded the image.

So my `users` table looks like this:

`+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id     | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NONE    | AUTO_INCREMENT |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

And my `picas` table looks like this:

`+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(1)      | NO   | PRI | NONE    | AUTO_INCREMENT |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id     | int(1)      | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

For now I have a problem with the newsfeed. It displays different users with their avatar and names, but if I post something when I'm logged in on an account, it posts for every user. So if I have 5 different users, I log in, I upload an image, then I see 5 posts instant. Check my screenshot here for better display --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf2Tr.png

Same goes for the title if you click the image. If I give up a title, then it shows also on the other users.
My code when I upload:

**uploadfile.php** here I store the uploaded file into the database.

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit_pica'])) {

    $newName = md5(time().$_FILES['pica']['tmp_name']).'.jpeg';

    $postTitle = $_POST['postTitle'];

    $ses_user = $_SESSION['username'];

    $getuserid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$ses_user'"));
    $userid = $getuserid['id'];

    $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO picas (id, name, title, created_at, user_id)
                            VALUES (null, '$newName', '$postTitle', null, '$userid')");

    echo "<script>
            $('.upload_button').click(function() {
                $('#uploadform').slideUp(300);
            });
         </script>";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pica']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$newName);

}

?>
```

**showimages.php** (here I output the images from the database.

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *
                          FROM picas, users
                          ORDER BY created_at DESC");


$ses_user = $_SESSION['username'];

while($pica = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<div class="image_post">
            <div class="user_avatar"><img src="avatars/'.$pica['username'].'.jpeg" /></div>
                <div class="user_name">'.$pica['username'].'</div> <br><br><br>
                <div class="image_title">'.$pica['title'].'</div>
                <img src="upload/'.$pica['name'].'" />
          </div>';

}

?>
```

My friend says I had to create a **foreign** key so it created a relationship between the `user_id` from `picas` and `user_id` from `users`.

Apparently it didn't work. I got the latest version from everything.

I can only choose from: `users` or `picas` table (logic, because those are the only ones I have) and then in the option field right next to it, I can only choose `id` or `user_id` (depends on which table I choose).

It gives me the this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wCmC.png
In the imgur link you see also what I fill in. I go to the table: **picas > structure > relation view**

It isn't working. I hope using the foreign key is the solution to this problem with the newsfeed, because I want that when the image is uploaded, it outputs the user who uploaded it with the uploaded image and not that it does that + every other user that is stored in the database. Please help me. I struggle with this for already a week. It's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the care you've taken writing this question.

Pro tip:  Avoid using `SELECT *` in queries in software. Using `SELECT *` allows you to be sloppy in your thinking about what you want in your result set.

Pro tip: If you want results from more than one table, use `JOIN` directives rather than a comma-separated list of tables. This makes you think clearly about how your tables relate to each other.

You're using this query to display your items.

```
SELECT *               /*wrong!*/
  FROM picas, users    /*combinatorial explosion!*/
 ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

This query assembles a result set using every possible combination of rows from `picas` and `users`. Lucky for you you don't have 50 users and 100 entries in `picas` yet, or this query would yield 5000 rows.

What you need for your query is something like this:

```
 SELECT users.user_id, users.username,
        picas.id, picas.name, picas.title, picas.created_at
   FROM users
   JOIN picas ON users.user_id = picas.userid
  WHERE users.username = '$ses_user'
  ORDER BY picas.created_at DESC
```

This will construct a resultset with the columns I've mentioned. It will use the criterion in the `ON` clause to join the data from the two tables in a way that makes sense.